# ANTLR v3: token file - 'array' and 'null'

Tags: antlr3

See [ANTLR v3: order token to improve performance of tree walker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22271958/antlr-v3-order-token-to-improve-performance-of-tree-walker) as pre-info

Unfortunately I have problems with 'array' and 'null' as tokens. If I specify them in the token file as follows:

```
TypeArray=394
'array'=394
Null=395
'null'=395
```

Then it seems that ANTLR does not recognise the tokens any more. I got the following error message when I am compiling the grammar:

```
TSPHP.g:582:4: no lexer rule corresponding to token: TypeArray
TSPHP.g:980:4: no lexer rule corresponding to token: Null
```

And furthermore when I am debugging:

```
[18:59:10] warning(24): template error: context [/outputFile /parser /genericParser /region__/genericParser__members /region__/genericParser__members /_sub290] 8:27 no such property or can't access: null.hasSynPred
```

How I am supposed to specify the tokens in order that it works?

**Edit:**
As additional information. When I generate the grammar file without using the tokenVocab option then it seems to work. When I then try to use the generated token file as input for tokenVocab then I get the following exception:

```
[18:49:28] error(10):  internal error: D:\TSPHP-parser\antlr\TSPHP.g : java.lang.NullPointerException
org.antlr.tool.AssignTokenTypesBehavior.aliasTokenIDsAndLiterals(AssignTokenTypesBehavior.java:278)
org.antlr.tool.AssignTokenTypesBehavior.defineTokens(AssignTokenTypesBehavior.java:215)
org.antlr.tool.CompositeGrammar.assignTokenTypes(CompositeGrammar.java:347)
org.antlr.Tool.process(Tool.java:481)
org.antlr.works.generate.CodeGenerate.generate(CodeGenerate.java:104)
org.antlr.works.generate.CodeGenerate.run(CodeGenerate.java:185)
```

java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

I realised that this was due to the token '\\' which needed to be specified as follows '\\\\'. But as soon as I have fixed this issue then I get the same problem again as above (no lexer rule....)

Comment: Might have to do with reserved names. Are Null and TypeArray keywords in your target language? It's generally better to use more unique symbol names. I always have a pattern like: PLUS_SYMBOL, IS_OPERATOR instead of PLUS, IS etc.

Comment: Btw, don't use quoted tokens! The token names are exactly as they will appear in the generated lexer/parser as source code elements.

Comment: the target language is Java and null is reserved but Null shouldn't be. However, I need to specify 'null' at some point, or how else should the lexer be able to map the token to my alias Null?
Btw. the name of the generated method is mNull not just Null

Comment: hmm, in Java generated lexer constants might not play a role much, in C it's more difficult, because the lexer tokens are defined as integer constants using the name given in the grammar. Hence my suggestion to ammend them with some extra letters to avoid any clash with existing identifiers.